# Let Web Api unpack and validate JSON posted via multipart/form-data

Tags: json, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data, model-binding, iformfile

I am sending `multipart/form-data` to one of my action methods, because in addition to JSON I need to upload a file. So on the server side it looks like this:

```
public class ItemPostRequest
{
    public List<Item> ItemsFromJson { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }        
    public string Amount { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("test")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> PostItem([FromForm] ItemPostRequest itemPostRequest)
{
    return Content("done", "application/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

And this is my request:

```
POST /api/items/test HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 55378de0-71a2-4762-ae78-b6683917dbf4
Host: localhost:44376
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------087805821886130931238212
Content-Length: 899
----------------------------087805821886130931238212
// =============== THE RELEVANT PART STARTS HERE ====================
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ItemsFromJson"       // <======= important part
                                                           // <======= is
[{"Description":"my first item","Amount":"123"}]           // <======= here
----------------------------087805821886130931238212
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="localhost-1610916507269.log"

<localhost-1610916507269.log>
----------------------------087805821886130931238212--
```

So, valid JSON is sent as `ItemsFromJson`, but model binding is not working. Note in the following screenshot that `ItemsFromJson.Count` is 0 though items were sent as `[{"Description":"my first item","Amount":"123"}]`.
[image]

How can I get JSON deserialization and especially model validation when sending a `multipart/form-data` request? I am aware that I could just create a string property in my `ItemPostRequest` class and manually deserialize the JSON. But that would still be missing the model validation in the `Item` class for the `Description` property!?

Comment: How do you send the request and add the Object to the request form, can you share the related code? I think perhaps when you add the parameters to the Form, you have serialized the ItemPostRequest object and convert the object to Json string. Try to change the code from `public async Task<ActionResult<string>> PostItem([FromForm] ItemPostRequest itemPostRequest){}` to `public async Task<ActionResult<string>> PostItem([FromForm] string ItemsFromJson, IFormFile File){}`.Besides, you could also try to use `var filesToDelete = HttpContext.Request.Form["ItemsFromJson"]` to get the data from Form.

Comment: @ZhiLv Thanks, but that would give the JSON as string, I want to deserialize it. See my answer below, it can be done with a `ModelBinder`

Comment: Yes, after getting the JSON string, we have to deserialize it. Then, if you want to check if the model is valid or not, you can use TryValidateModel() method, check [Rerun validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#rerun-validation).